# How do I edit a variable that's in a different class

Tags: java

so I have 2 classes. let's call one Main and one Sub. 
**Main Class**

```java
public static boolean variable;
public static main(){
    variable = false;

    sub();

    while(variable == false){
        //pause for 1 millisecond
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch(Exception s){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected exception:" + s);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("compleate");
}
```

**Sub Class**

```java
import package.Main;

public static sub(){
    //wait for 3 seconds
    try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch(Exception s){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected exception:" + s);
        }
    Main.varaible = true;
}
```

I need a way to edit variables from Sub so that my program can continue.

I have tried the above Sub class but I don't think that works (i have tried testing this, and it didn't work but it was in a big program with a lot going on, so I am not sure that there wasn't another problem)

Comment: yes, I have tried, but it was in a big program and I am not entirely sure that the problem is not elsewhere.

Comment: What kind of variable? Instance or Static? Public or Private?

Comment: main is public static

Comment: Normally, if a class allows modification of it's instance variables, it exposes getter and setter methods.

Comment: Add `Sub` class code to your question.

Comment: realized I made a mistake about how t variable was defined. Main class has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the variable in main if it is a public field on the class. What you have right now is a variable defined inside the scope of a function, you can't access it outside of the function